# MediaPlayer - Only the second element in listview is playing

Tags: android, listview

I am having trouble with being able to play music that I put into a listview. I believe it is a problem with the prepare() function or the index(which I don't know why that would be the case. I have researched this a lot and trial and error. I still can't figure it out. Thanks for all the help.

Source code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Audio;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity{

    ListView lv;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    int music_column_index;
    Cursor c;
    int currentPosition;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lv = getListView();


        c = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        null, null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC");
        String[] cols = new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE};
        int[] views = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, cols, views,0);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //System.out.println(c.getString(position));
                try {

                    mp = new MediaPlayer();
                    //mp.setDataSource(c.getString(position));
                    mp.setDataSource(c.getString(position));
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println(ex);
                } 

            }


        });

       }











    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: c is a cursor, you should use c.movetoposition(position) and then get the uri for the song. make sure the cursor has data and the position is not out of the cursor's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes try to move your cursor position before media prepare. Good Luck! **c.moveToPosition(position);**

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    //System.out.println(c.getString(position));
                    try {
                        c.moveToPosition(position);
                        mp = new MediaPlayer();
                        //mp.setDataSource(c.getString(position));
                        mp.setDataSource(c.getString(position));
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    } 

                }


            });
```